# Google barchart side label cuts off

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Right so I have my chart set up but the side labels or bar titles are cut off if they don't fit in the div of the graph, so my question is, is there anyway to overflow the bar titles of the graph(the font size is getting too small to read so I can't make it any smaller) or even wrap the text.

Well seeing as I don't think the code will help I'll show it regardless, mind you I have limited space and I am showing 2 graphs in that space. All I need is the side labels to have overflow: show(so if the specific bar label overflows the area it displays..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="myChart" style="width:50%"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var id = "myChart";
    var chartData= [["The big label that is the issue in this case we need this to display  its overflow","74","",""],["Louise","71","",""],["Louise.v.2","0","",""],["member1","72","",""],["member3","67","",""]];

    var defaultColors = ["#3366cc", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618", "#990099", "#0099c6", "#dd4477", "#66aa00",
"#b82e2e", "#316395", "#994499", "#22aa99", "#aaaa11", "#6633cc", "#e67300", "#8b0707", "#651067", "#329262",
"#5574a6", "#3b3eac", "#b77322", "#16d620", "#b91383", "#f4359e", "#9c5935", "#a9c413", "#2a778d", "#668d1c",
"#bea413", "#0c5922", "#743411"];

    var counter = 0;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', '');
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: "style" });
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation' });
    if (chartData[0][3].length > 0) {
        data.addColumn('number', '');
    }

    data.addRows(chartData.length + 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
         var thisItem = chartData[i];
         data.setCell(i, 0, thisItem[0]);
         data.setCell(i, 1, thisItem[1]);
         if (thisItem[2].length > 0) {
              data.setCell(i, 2, "color: #000000");
         } else {
              data.setCell(i, 2, "color: " + defaultColors[counter]);
         }
         data.setCell(i, 3, thisItem[1] + "%");
         if (thisItem[3].length > 0) {
              data.setCell(i, 4, thisItem[3]);
         }
         counter = counter + 1;
         if (counter == 31) {
             counter = 0;
         }
     }

     var barChart = null;
     var options = null;

     barChart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById(id));

     var fullHeight = ((chartData.length + 1) * 20) + 50;
     var minHieght = 200;

     options = {
         height: fullHeight,
         tooltip: { isHtml: true },
         max: 100,
         label: 'value',
         orientation: 'vertical',
         fontSize: 15,
         width: (((($(window).width() / 3) * 2) / 5) * 3),
         legend: { position: 'none' },
         bar: { groupWidth: 15, width: 20 },
         chartArea: { height: fullHeight - 50, width: "47%", left: "50%", top: 0 },
         backgroundColor: 'transparent',
         enableInteractivity: false,
         legend: 'none',
         seriesType: 'bars',
         series: { 1: { type: 'line', lineWidth: 5, enableInteractivity: false, color: 'grey' } },
         annotations: {
             alwaysOutside: true
         }
    };

    barChart.draw(data, options);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Done. 15 characters for a comment....

Comment: show full html or create fiddle

Comment: Done, although I have removed any unnessasary code for this example.(the width is to remain as is.)